# Problem while using getline command in C++

Tags: c++, getline

I have used getline command in the simplest possible way but when I am running my program, it is not allowing me to enter the input and is directly showing the next output statement.

The code snippet is as follows :

```
void Account::change_name () {
    std::cout << "Enter the new name : ";
    std::string changed_name {};
    std::getline (std::cin,changed_name);
    name = changed_name;
    std::cout << "The name of the A/c has been changed to : " << name << std::endl;
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: Let me guess: You have some other input operations before you call `change_name`, one which uses the "input operator" `>>`?

Comment: Do you have `std::cin >>` somewhere before this getline?

Comment: long answer short, `std::getline (std::cin.ignore(),changed_name);`